# Object returning three value instead of one. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, syntax-error

I have used following code:

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{ 
$sfees = sfee::where('student_id', $sid)->first(['mfee_id']);//mfee_id is the column I'm trying to recover
 foreach ($sfees as $sfee) {

    echo $sfee;

 }
```

The problem is that it is returning three 1. While it was supposed to return only one.
If i echo $sfees before foreach it returns only one value: {"mfee_id":1}.
What is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for one model, you don't need to try and iterate it, its a single model (object). (`first()` can return null though, so you should check)

```
$sfees->mfee_id;
```

If you just want the value of that column for that one record:

```
$mfee_id = sfee::where('student_id', $sid)->value('mfee_id');
```

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results)

Comment: It worked for 1 value. But there are also multiple values like, there are multiple student_id with different mfee_id in the linking table. In case of multiple value too it is returning only one value.

Comment: I think you should update your question with what you are actually trying to do :)  Because `first` means 1 and you are passing it array of fields you want, which is one field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` statement for returning from function, not `echo`.

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{ 
    $sfees = sfee::where('student_id', $sid)->first(['mfee_id']);//mfee_id is the column I'm trying to recover

    return $some_variable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that that your trying to itterate over a single model. That's cause that you itterate over attributes and you get odd result the only think that you need is to do like this:

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{ 
    $sfees = sfee::where('student_id', $sid)->first(['mfee_id']);//mfee_id 

    echo $sfees->mfee_id;
 }
```

`$sfees` in this example is a single model not a collection of models becasuse you've used `first` to get it.